# How to get first key from JObject?

Tags: wpf, json.net

I am using `Newtonsoft.Json` in my project. I have `JObject` like this:

```
{
    "4781":"Name 1",
    "1577":"Name 2",
    "9973":"Name 3"
}
```

I successfully parse it with `JObject.Parse()`. I need to get first key from this JObject ("4781"). How do I get it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Json.NET doesn't **directly** provide integer indexed access to the properties of a [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm).

If you do `JObject.Parse(jsonString)[0]` you get an `ArgumentException` with the message

> Accessed JObject values with invalid key value: 0. Object property name expected."

Demo #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dZnmhQ).

I suspect Json.NET was implemented that way because the [JSON standard](https://json.org/) states, "An *object* is an **unordered** set of name/value pairs."

That being said, `JObject` inherits from [`JContainer`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer.htm) which does [*explicitly*](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JContainer.cs#L920) implement `IList<JToken>`.  Thus if you upcast a `JObject` to `IList<JToken>` you can access the properties by an integer index corresponding to document order:

```
IList<JToken> obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var firstName = ((JProperty)obj[0]).Name;
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5pn93V).

Alternatively you could use LINQ for a type-safe solution without any casting:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;


var obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var firstName = obj.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).FirstOrDefault();
```

Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Am7qFA).