# Getting to extension attributes of Azure user via PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, rest

I'm trying to get to Azure user extension properties which are synced via AADC (Azure AD Connect) from on-prem to target tenant. As a pre-reading -> good article here : https://www.xtseminars.co.uk/post/azure-ad-schema-and-directory-extensions.

The issue is that those extensions might be or not populated on target user object. So let assume that with single REST API call (*https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=id,extension_c16821412f864d419a92205ad4820f0c_something&$top=5*) I get following response:

```
$json = '{
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "91c0b90e-4ed0-4c69-8b96-b67c07bbb061"
        },
        {
            "id": "fdcd34dc-e7ab-4045-881d-0fee024c2b55",
            "extension_c16821412f864d419a92205ad4820f0c_something": "INXXXXXX213423"
        },
        {
            "id": "90ebc867-6a67-4cf0-a5d9-e4c07c9d3905"
        },
        {
            "id": "80134f5f-892f-4800-9087-924a0c69b7f1"
        },
        {
            "id": "36fae4de-c685-4da5-9458-e165d99fe670"
        }
    ]
}'
```

Question is - how to nicely get to note properties which are defined 'optionally' ?
As below gives just id:

```
PS> ($json | ConvertFrom-Json).value

id
--
91c0b90e-4ed0-4c69-8b96-b67c07bbb061
fdcd34dc-e7ab-4045-881d-0fee024c2b55
90ebc867-6a67-4cf0-a5d9-e4c07c9d3905
80134f5f-892f-4800-9087-924a0c69b7f1
36fae4de-c685-4da5-9458-e165d99fe670
```

Or in general - is it even doable with ConvertFrom-JSON() ?

Comment: What is your expected output format?

Comment: Might be new PSobject with all properties - it really doesn't matter. The question is - is it expected that Convertfrom-json() trimms down properties which are not visible on every instance of returned JSON response ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, seems after reading this nice piece - [Understanding NewtonSoft in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58141125/understanding-newtonsoft-in-powershell) was able to figure out the solution using newtonsoft.json module

```
PS > Import-Module newtonsoft.json
PS >
PS > $json = '{
>> "value": [
>>         {
>>             "id": "91c0b90e-4ed0-4c69-8b96-b67c07bbb061"
>>         },
>>         {
>>             "id": "fdcd34dc-e7ab-4045-881d-0fee024c2b55",
>>             "extension_somedata": "XXXXXX213423"
>>         },
>>         {
>>             "id": "90ebc867-6a67-4cf0-a5d9-e4c07c9d3905"
>>         },
>>         {
>>             "id": "80134f5f-892f-4800-9087-924a0c69b7f1"
>>         },
>>         {
>>             "id": "36fae4de-c685-4da5-9458-e165d99fe670"
>>         }
>>     ]
>> }'
PS >
PS >
PS > $u = ($json |ConvertFrom-JsonNewtonsoft).value
PS > $u

Name                           Value
----                           -----
id                             91c0b90e-4ed0-4c69-8b96-b67c07bbb061
id                             fdcd34dc-e7ab-4045-881d-0fee024c2b55
extension_somedata             XXXXXX213423
id                             90ebc867-6a67-4cf0-a5d9-e4c07c9d3905
id                             80134f5f-892f-4800-9087-924a0c69b7f1
id                             36fae4de-c685-4da5-9458-e165d99fe670


PS > $allRows = @()
PS > foreach($o in $u){
>> $lineObject = New-Object PSObject
>>             add-member -inputobject $lineObject -membertype noteproperty -name "id" -value $o.id
>>             add-member -inputobject $lineObject -membertype noteproperty -name "extension_somedata" -value $o.extension_somedata
>> $allRows+=$lineObject
>> }
PS >
PS > $allRows

id                                   extension_somedata
--                                   ------------------
91c0b90e-4ed0-4c69-8b96-b67c07bbb061
fdcd34dc-e7ab-4045-881d-0fee024c2b55 XXXXXX213423
90ebc867-6a67-4cf0-a5d9-e4c07c9d3905
80134f5f-892f-4800-9087-924a0c69b7f1
36fae4de-c685-4da5-9458-e165d99fe670
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you shouldn't need another module as it is possible with **[ConvertFrom-JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7)** itself, but with an additional parameter **[-AsHashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7#example-4--convert-a-json-string-to-a-hash-table)**.

There are some constraints with the `ConvertFrom-JSON` cmdlet and `-AsHashtable` helps overcome some of them. Quoting from the docs:

> - If the JSON contains a list with keys that only differ in casing. Without the switch, those keys would be seen as identical keys and
>   therefore only the last one would get used.
> - If the JSON contains a key that is an empty string. Without the switch, the cmdlet would throw an error since a `PSCustomObject` does
>   not allow for that but a hash table does. An example use case where
>   this can occurs are `project.lock.json` files.
> - Hash tables can be processed faster for certain data structures.

Do note that this switch was introduced in **PowerShell 6.0**.

Applying this to the same example that you specified:

```
PS > $json = '{
>>     "value": [
>>         {
>>             "id": "91c0b90e-4ed0-4c69-8b96-b67c07bbb061"
>>         },
>>         {
>>             "id": "fdcd34dc-e7ab-4045-881d-0fee024c2b55",
>>             "extension_somedata": "INXXXXXX213423"
>>         },
>>         {
>>             "id": "90ebc867-6a67-4cf0-a5d9-e4c07c9d3905"
>>         },
>>         {
>>             "id": "80134f5f-892f-4800-9087-924a0c69b7f1"
>>         },
>>         {
>>             "id": "36fae4de-c685-4da5-9458-e165d99fe670"
>>         }
>>     ]
>> }'
PS >
PS > $u = ($json | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable).value
PS >
PS > $u

Name                           Value
----                           -----
id                             91c0b90e-4ed0-4c69-8b96-b67c07bbb061
id                             fdcd34dc-e7ab-4045-881d-0fee024c2b55
extension_somedata             INXXXXXX213423
id                             90ebc867-6a67-4cf0-a5d9-e4c07c9d3905
id                             80134f5f-892f-4800-9087-924a0c69b7f1
id                             36fae4de-c685-4da5-9458-e165d99fe670

PS > $allRows = @()
PS >
PS > foreach($o in $u){
>>     $lineObject = New-Object PSObject
>>     Add-Member -InputObject $lineObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "id" -Value $o.id
>>     Add-Member -InputObject $lineObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "extension_somedata" -Value $o.extension_somedata
>>     $allRows+=$lineObject
>> }
PS >
PS > $allRows

id                                   extension_somedata
--                                   ------------------
91c0b90e-4ed0-4c69-8b96-b67c07bbb061
fdcd34dc-e7ab-4045-881d-0fee024c2b55 INXXXXXX213423
90ebc867-6a67-4cf0-a5d9-e4c07c9d3905
80134f5f-892f-4800-9087-924a0c69b7f1
36fae4de-c685-4da5-9458-e165d99fe670
```

References:

- [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7)
- [-AsHashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7#parameters)

Comment: Hello Bhargavi.

Indeed - figured out the same in the later stage, that **AsHashTable** provides the same results, but I don't have to use external module.

But really appreciate above!

Comment: @PeterS. Thank you! :) Please [mark the response](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped so it benefits others in the community with similar asks.