# What is the ParameterizedProperty Chars property on the string type added there by the Powershell?

Tags: string, powershell

Please, observe:

```
C:\> ''|Get-Member |? { $_.MemberType -eq 'ParameterizedProperty' }


   TypeName: System.String

Name  MemberType            Definition
----  ----------            ----------
Chars ParameterizedProperty char Chars(int index) {get;}


C:\>
```

This is a very weird property. First of all it is added by Powershell, next it contains an infinite recursive property:

```
C:\> ''.Chars


IsSettable          : False
IsGettable          : True
OverloadDefinitions : {char Chars(int index) {get;}}
TypeNameOfValue     : System.Char
MemberType          : ParameterizedProperty
Value               : char Chars(int index) {get;}
Name                : Chars
IsInstance          : True



C:\> ''.Chars.Value


IsSettable          : False
IsGettable          : True
OverloadDefinitions : {char Chars(int index) {get;}}
TypeNameOfValue     : System.Char
MemberType          : ParameterizedProperty
Value               : char Chars(int index) {get;}
Name                : Chars
IsInstance          : True



C:\> ''.Chars.GetHashCode()
56544304
C:\> ''.Chars.Value.GetHashCode()
34626228
C:\> ''.Chars.Value.Value.GetHashCode()
3756075
C:\> ''.Chars.Value.Value.Value.GetHashCode()
49108342
C:\> ''.Chars.Value.Value.Value.Value.GetHashCode()
62340979
C:\> ''.Chars.Value.Value.Value.Value.Value.GetHashCode()
24678148
C:\>
```

The hash code is different every time, so it must be dynamically generated.

Why do I care? I am trying to use a [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/newtonsoft.json/1.0.1.2) PowerShell module from PSGallery and it chokes on this property, but only when run in Desktop PowerShell (5.1), not the Core (7.0.3). The problem is that I do not have a minimal reproduction, the input object is quite large. The error I get is:

```
ConvertTo-JsonNewtonsoft : Exception calling "SerializeObject" with "2" argument(s): "Self referencing loop detected for property 'Value' with type 'System.Management.Automation.PSParameterizedProperty'. Path 'environments[4].conditions.name.Chars'."
```

No such problem exists in PS Core.

Can someone explain to me what is this property, why we need it and how can we get rid of it?

**EDIT 1**

I guess it is a problem with the `Newtonsoft.Json` module. Observe:

```
[DBG]> [pscustomobject]@{ a = 1} | ConvertTo-Json
{
  "a": 1
}
 [DBG]>  [pscustomobject]@{ a = 1} | ConvertTo-JsonNewtonsoft
{
  "CliXml": "<Objs Version=\"1.1.0.1\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04\">\r\n  <Obj RefId=\"0\">\r\n    <TN RefId=\"0\">\r\n
 <T>System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject</T>\r\n      <T>System.Object</T>\r\n    </TN>\r\n    <ToString>@{a=1}</ToString>\r\n    <Obj RefId=\"1\">\r\n      <TNRef RefId=\"0\" />\r\n      <MS>\r\n        <I32 N=\"a\">1</I32>\r\n      </MS>\r\n    </Obj>\r\n    <MS>\r\n      <I32 N=\"a\">1</I32>\r\n    </MS>\r\n  </Obj>\r\n</Objs>"
}
 [DBG]>
```

It is unable to properly interpret powershell objects. Makes it unusable.

Comment: As far as what the property is, 'hello'.Chars(0) evaluates to 'h'.  That tells me that it's pulling back the character at the position specified (as a character, not a string).

Comment: The parameterized property itself _isn't_ added by PowerShell - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.string.chars. It is only PowerShell's way of _reflecting_ that property that introduces the loop. But the question is: why is the serialization trying to reflect on the properties of a _string_ instance, which shouldn't really happen? Is there an invisible `[psobject]` wrapper involved?

Comment: @mklement0 - please see EDIT 1. The library is bonkers. I will ask another question about json and powershell.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58169326/45375

Comment: Looking at your edit, it looks like it's asking the `[psobject]` == `[pscustomobject]` instance to _serialize itself_ (via `System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable`) - which is not surprising, given that the dynamic properties of a PS custom objects aren't properties in a .NET sense. What you're seeing is the CLIXML serialization of a PS custom object.

Comment: I figured it out. Could you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64189660/how-to-serialize-an-object-in-powershell-to-json-and-get-identical-result-in-ps ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Your real problem is that **neither the [`Newtonsoft.Json` library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) nor the [PowerShell wrapper module for it](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/newtonsoft.json) support `[pscustomobject]` instances**:

The library asks `[pscustomobject]` instances to *serialize themselves*, based on the `[pscustomobject]` (`[psobject]`) implementing the `ISerializable` interface.

- In Windows PowerShell this happens to fail outright, presumably due to the bundled version of the `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` assembly being quite old (as of this writing, the bundled version is `8.0`, whereas `12.0`is current) and having a *bug*

  - The manifestation of this bug is the `Self referencing loop detected for property 'Value' ...` bug you saw.
- In PowerShell [Core] v6+, the newer version of `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` that ships with PowerShell itself *preempts* the obsolete version, so the error doesn't occur, but the serialization problem becomes obvious:

  - The resulting `{ "CliXml": "<Objs Version=\"1.1.0.1\" .. }` JSON text shows that the `[pscustomobject]` instance was serialized in CLIXML format, PowerShell's native XML-based serialization format, as notably used by PowerShell's remoting feature.
  - It is hypothetically possible - though very cumbersome - to *manually* deserialize such JSON by post-processing it and replacing objects with only a `CliXml` property with the return value from [`[System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer.Deserialize)

---

**Solutions**:

- If your intent is simply to compare serialized representations in a PS-edition-agnostic form, *irrespective of the specific serialization format*, consider using CLIXML directly, via `Export-CliXml` and `Import-CliXml`.
- If you do want a PS-edition-agnostic way to serialize to *JSON*, you'll have to roll your own `[pscustomobject]`-to-ordered-hashtable converter, because serializing ordered hashtables (`[ordered] @{ ... }`, [`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary)) via Newtonsoft.Json *does* round-trip properly in PowerShell (it is, in fact, the data structure used by the `ConvertFrom/To-JsonNewtonsoft` wrapper cmdlets).

Both approaches are demonstrated in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64209181/45375).