# How to serialize an object in powershell to json and get identical result in PS desktop and core?

Tags: json, powershell

**Prolog**

It turns out that in my case it is important to understand the source of the objects - it is a JSON payload from a REST API response. Unfortunately, **JSON -> Object** conversion produces different results on PS desktop vs PS core. On desktop the numbers are deserialized into `Int32` types, but on core - to `Int64` types. From that it follows that I cannot use `Export-CliXml`, because the binary layout of the objects is different.

**Main question**

I have a unit test that needs to compare the actual result with an expected. The expected result is saved in a json file, so the procedure is:

1. Convert the actual result to json string
2. Read the expected result from disk to string
3. Compare the actual and the expected as strings

Unfortunately, this scheme does not work because PS desktop `ConvertTo-Json` and PS core `ConvertTo-Json` do not produce identical results. So, if the expected result was saved on desktop and the test runs on core - boom, failure. And vice versa.

One way is to keep two versions of jsons. Another way is to use a library to create the json.

First I tried the [Newtonsoft-Json](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/newtonsoft.json/1.0.1.2) powershell module, but it just [does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64189421/what-is-the-parameterizedproperty-chars-property-on-the-string-type-added-there#64189421). I think the problem is that whatever C# library we use, it must be aware of `PSCustomObject` and alike and treat them specially. So, we cannot just take any C# JSON library.

At this point I am left with having two jsons - one per PS edition, which is kind of sad.

Are there better options?

**EDIT 1**

I guess I can always read the json, convert to object and then back to json again. That sucks.

**EDIT 2**

I tried to use `ConvertTo-Json -Compress`. This eliminates the difference in spacing, but the problem is that for some reason the desktop version translates all the non characters to `\u000...` representation. The core version does not do it.

Please, observe:

**Desktop**

```
C:\> @{ x = "'a'" } |ConvertTo-Json -Compress
{"x":"\u0027a\u0027"}
C:\>
```

**Core**

```
C:\>  @{ x = "'a'" } |ConvertTo-Json -Compress
{"x":"'a'"}
C:\>
```

Now the core version has the flag `-EscapeHandling`, so:

```
C:\>  @{ x = "'a'" } |ConvertTo-Json -Compress -EscapeHandling EscapeHtml
{"x":"\u0027a\u0027"}
C:\>
```

Bingo! Same result. But now this code does not run on the desktop version, which does not have this flag. More massaging is needed. I will check if that is the only problem.

**EDIT 3**

It is impossible to reconcile the differences between the core and the desktop versions without expensive post processing. Please, observe:

**Desktop**

```
C:\> @{ x = '"a"';y = "'b'" } |ConvertTo-Json -Compress
{"y":"\u0027b\u0027","x":"\"a\""}
C:\>
```

**Core**

```
C:\> @{ x = '"a"';y = "'b'" } |ConvertTo-Json -Compress -EscapeHandling EscapeHtml
{"y":"\u0027b\u0027","x":"\u0022a\u0022"}
C:\> @{ x = '"a"';y = "'b'" } |ConvertTo-Json -Compress
{"y":"'b'","x":"\"a\""}
C:\>
```

Any suggestions on how to salvage the json approach?

**EDIT 4**

The `Export-CliXml` approach does not work too, because of the differences between the PS versions.

**Desktop**

```
C:\> ('{a:1}' | ConvertFrom-Json).a.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType


C:\>
```

**Core**

```
C:\> ('{a:1}' | ConvertFrom-Json).a.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Int64                                    System.ValueType

C:\>
```

So the same JSON is represented using different numeric types - `Int32` in desktop and `Int64` in core. That puts to bed the option of using `Export-CliXml`.

Unless I am missing something.

I believe there is no other choice, but do the double conversion - **json -> object -> json** and then I will have two jsons created on the same PS edition. That sucks big time.

Comment: Do you need to use JSON? How about `Export-CliXml`, which uses PowerShell's native CLIXML serialization format - whether it works 100% the same across PS editions I don't know.

Comment: I can try, but these are big objects. I will check, though.

Comment: There's a `-Depth` parameter, which defaults to 2, which prevents runaway serialization with non-`[pscustom]` objects.

Comment: Do you mean they are different in spacing? You could simply compress them and compare? `Convertto-json -compress`

Comment: Not only. I noticed some `\u000...` characters in one of them. Let me check, I will update the post.

Comment: @mklement0, just like with `ConvertTo-Json`, I am passing `-Depth 99`.

Comment: @DougMaurer - I am exploring this direction. Please, see **EDIT 2**

Comment: @DougMaurer - please, see **EDIT 3**

Comment: @mklement0 - `Export-CliXml` is not an option either. Please, see **EDIT 4**.

Comment: @mark: The suggestion was to use `Export-CliXml` _instead_ of `ConvertTo-Json`.

Comment: I know. But my original input is JSON coming from a web server. I convert it to objects and then persist on disk in order to write unit tests. So, `JSON -> Object -> Export-CliXml` on desktop gives a different result from `JSON -> Object -> Export-CliXml` on core. I realize now it is not a problem with `Export-CliXml`, but what can I do?

Comment: What about [exporting it to a PowerShell expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24854277/1701026) using [`ConvertTo-Expression`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression) `-Strong`. It might be less convenient to serialize (using a external cmdlet) but it is very easy to "deserialize" (use) in e.g. tests knowing that it is also used for [a specific DSC module](https://github.com/iRon7/ConvertTo-Expression/pull/2).

Comment: @iRon - this is a very interesting idea. I will give it a try.

Comment: @iRon - that would work too. But at the end I have settled on a dumb, but simple solution that does extra JSON deserialization-serialization round-trip because it is acceptable performance wise and does not require any extra dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- On **converting *from* the original JSON**, use the **third-party [Newtonsoft.Json PowerShell wrapper](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/newtonsoft.json/1.0.1.2)'s  `ConvertFrom-JsonNewtonsoft` cmdlet** - this should ensure cross-edition compatibility (which the built-in `ConvertFrom-Json` does *not* guarantee across PowerShell editions, because Windows PowerShell uses a custom parser, whereas PowerShell [Core] v6+ uses Newtonsoft.json up to at least v7.1, though a [move to the new(ish) .NET Core  `System.Text.Json` API](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/11198) is coming).

  - **Important**: `ConvertFrom-JsonNewtonsoft` returns (arrays of)  nested *ordered hashtables* (`[ordered] @{ ... }`, [`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary)), unlike the nested  `[pscustomobject]` graphs that the built-in `ConvertFrom-Json` outputs. Similarly, `ConvertTo-JsonNewtonsoft` expects only (arrays of) hashtables (dictionaries) as input, and notably does *not* support `[pscustomobject]` instances, [as you've learned yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64189421/45375).

    - **Caveat**: As of this writing, the wrapper module was last updated in May 2019, and the version of the underlying bundled `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` assembly is quite old (`8.0`, whereas `12.0` is [current](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) as of this writing). See the module's [source code](https://github.com/qbikez/ps-entropy/tree/master/newtonsoft.json/src).
  - Note that in order **to parse JSON obtained from a RESTful web service *manually***, you mustn't use [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod), as it *implicitly* parses and returns `[pscustomobject]` object graphs. Instead, **use [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest)** and access the returned response's `.Content` property.
- On **converting *to* a format suitable for storing on disk**, you have two options:

  - (A) **If you do need the serialized format to be JSON also**, you **must convert all `[pscustomobject]` graphs to *(ordered) hashtables* before passing them to `ConvertTo-JsonNewtonsoft`**.

    - See below for function `ConvertTo-OrderedHashTable`, which does just that.
  - (B) **If the specific serialization format isn't important**, i.e. if all that matters is that the formats are identical across PowerShell editions for the purpose of comparison, no extra works is needed: use the built-in **[`Export-Clixml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-clixml)** cmdlet, which **can handle *any* type** and produces **PowerShell's native, XML-based serialization format called CLIXML** (as notably used in PowerShell remoting), which should be cross-edition-compatible (at least with v5.1 on the Windows PowerShell side and as of PowerShell [Core] v7.1, both of which use the same version of the serialization protocol, `1.1.0.1`, as reported by `$PSVersionTable.SerializationVersion`).

    - While you could re-convert such a persisted file to *objects* with [`Import-Clixml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-clixml), the [*potential loss of type fidelity*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375) on deserialization makes comparing the *serialized* (CLIXML) representations advisable.
    - Also note that as of PowerShell v7.1 there is no cmdlet-based way to create an *in-memory* CLIXML representation, so you'll have to use the PowerShell API directly for now: [`System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer.Serialize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer.Serialize). However, providing in-memory counterparts to `Import-CliXml` / `Export-CliXml` in the form of `ConvertFrom-CliXml` / `ConvertTo-CliXml` cmdlets has been [green-lighted as a future enhancement](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3898).

---

Re (A): Here's **function `ConvertTo-OrderedHashtable`**, which converts (potentially nested) `[pscustomobject]` objects to ordered hashtables while passing other types through, so you should be able to simply insert it into a pipeline as follows:

```bash
# CAVEAT: ConvertTo-JsonNewtonSoft only accepts a *single* input object.
[pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1 }, [pscustomobject] @{ foo = 2 } | 
  ConvertTo-OrderedHashtable |
    ForEach-Object { ConvertTo-JsonNewtonSoft $_ }
```

```bash
function ConvertTo-OrderedHashtable {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Converts custom objects to ordered hashtables.

.DESCRIPTION
Converts PowerShell custom objects (instances of [pscustomobject]) to
ordered hashtables (instances of [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]),
which is useful for to-JSON serialization via the Newtonsoft.JSON library.

Note: 
 * Custom objects are processed recursively.
 * Any scalar non-custom objects are passed through as-is.
 * Any (non-dictionary) collections in property values are converted to 
  [object[]] arrays.

.EXAMPLE
1, [pscustomobject] @{ foo = [pscustomobject] @{ bar = 'none' }; other = 2 } | ConvertTo-OrderedHashtable

Passes integer 1 through, and converts the custom object to a nested ordered
hashtable.
#>
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] $InputObject
  )

  begin {

    # Recursive helper function
    function convert($obj) {
      if ($obj -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]) {
        # a custom object: recurse on its properties
        $oht = [ordered] @{ }
        foreach ($prop in $obj.psobject.Properties) {
          $oht.Add($prop.Name, (convert $prop.Value))
        }
        return $oht
      }
      elseif ($obj -isnot [string] -and $obj -is [System.Collections.IEnumerable] -and $obj -isnot [System.Collections.IDictionary]) {
        # A collection of sorts (other than a string or dictionary (hash table)), recurse on its elements.
        return @(foreach ($el in $obj) { convert $el })
      }
      else { 
        # a non-custom object, including .NET primitives and strings: use as-is.
        return $obj
      }
    }

  }

  process {

    convert $InputObject

  }

}
```

---

Re (B): **A demonstration of the `Export-CliXml` approach** (you can run this code from either PS edition):

```bash
$sb = {

  Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser Newtonsoft.json
  if (-not $IsCoreClr) { 
    # Workaround for PS Core's $env:PSModulePath overriding WinPS'
    Import-Module $HOME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\newtonsoft.json
  }
  @'
  {
      "results": {
          "users": [
              {
                  "userId": 1,
                  "emailAddress": "jane.doe@example.com",
                  "date": "2020-10-05T08:08:43.743741-04:00",
                  "attributes": {
                      "height": 165,
                      "weight": 60
                  }
              },
              {
                  "userId": 2,
                  "emailAddress": "john.doe@example.com",
                  "date": "2020-10-06T08:08:43.743741-04:00",
                  "attributes": {
                      "height": 180,
                      "weight": 72
                  }
              }
          ]
      }
  }
'@ | ConvertFrom-JsonNewtonsoft | Export-CliXml "temp-$($PSVersionTable.PSEdition).xml"
  
}
  
# Execute the script block in both editions

Write-Verbose -vb 'Running in Windows PowerShell...'
powershell -noprofile $sb

Write-Verbose -vb 'Running in PowerShell Core...'
pwsh -noprofile $sb
  
# Compare the resulting CLIXML files.
Write-Verbose -vb "Comparing the resulting files: This should produce NO output,`n         indicating that the files have identical content."
Compare-Object (Get-Content 'temp-Core.xml') (Get-Content 'temp-Desktop.xml')

Write-Verbose -vb 'Cleaning up...'
Remove-Item 'temp-Core.xml', 'temp-Desktop.xml'
```

You should see the following verbose output:

```
VERBOSE: Running in Windows PowerShell...
VERBOSE: Running in PowerShell Core...
VERBOSE: Comparing the resulting files: This should produce NO output, 
         indicating that the files have identical content.
VERBOSE: Cleaning up...
```